# Enthusiast no more?

Tags: support, activity-badges

I crossed 30 consecutive days 2 days ago (today is 32nd) but I didn't get an Enthusiast badge this time around.

BTW, I did change my openid this week but as per [this question answered by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32312/enthusiast-badge-not-awarded-if-i-changed-my-user-name-or-swapped-my-open-id) that should make no difference.

So, is the enthusiast badge like a one time thing?

Or

Should I expect to get it everytime I have 30 consecutive days?

If it is the latter, then "Hand over the badge p##k"? :-) :-)
*PS: I am feeling lucky today*.

Comment: Get all of your badge questions answered at [What is each badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge) Enthusiast is a one-time-only badge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Enthusiast -- Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days.*

Badges that can be awarded multiple times will say in its description "this badge can be awarded multiple times." Simple, no?

Comment: actually it is not simple / clear atleast to me. None of the descriptions seem to explitly mention "this badge can be awarded multiple times" at http://stackoverflow.com/badges

Comment: @InSane the individual badge pages do explicitly mention it, such as http://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question. If it doesn't mention it on the page then it's not a bade you can earn more than once.

Comment: Aah..i get it!! Never actually saw that there were detail pages for each badge! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There's always Fanatic.

Comment: Yup...theres fanatic...and i  seriously doubt i can stretch to that one..but who knows? we will see :-)

Comment: @InSane:  Pick a time when you aren't going to go on any vacations away from internet connectivity.  Know when midnight UTC is where you live.  For me, it was 6 PM on standard time, 7 when on daylight saving.  That made it feasible to skip a whole Saturday if needed:  log in at 7:30 Friday and 5 PM Sunday and I still made progress.

Comment: @David - Thanks! That is an excellent point :-) I will note the UTC time difference.